# Reactjs - ComponentWillUpdate method not getting executed with enzyme mount

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

i am trying to test my react component which has some conditional rendering logic in it. I added the code below. Can someone please help me understand as to why ComponentWillUpdate is not getting called when the component is mounted using enzyme? I need this method to execute since user permissions for viewing the page are set in this method.

Component.js

```
class CaseFileLinksComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            AccessMatrix: {
                writelink:false,
            },
            isPrivilegesLoaded: false,
            linkURL: '',
            linkDesc: '',
            modalFields: {
              IsModalOpen: false,
              HeaderContent: "",
              ConfirmBtnText: "",
              data: {}
            },
            folderLinks: [{ linkDesc: 'something', linkUrl: 'something' }],
            folderGridLabels: this.getLinkGridLabels()
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLinkGridLabels();
        this.getAllFolderLinks();
    }
    componentWillUpdate =() =>
    {
        if(this.props?.userSession?.userPrivileges&& !this.state.isPrivilegesLoaded)
        {
          this.handleUpdateAccess(this.props.userSession.userPrivileges);
          
        }
    }
    handleLinkInputChanges = (event, fieldName) => {
        let currentState = { ...this.state };
        if (this.state.folderLinks.length === 0) {
            this.setState({ folderLinks: [{}] })
        }
        currentState[fieldName] = event;
        this.setState({ ...currentState });
    }

    selectedData = () => {

    }

    onDataTableCellClick = (event) => {
        if (event.field === "delete" && event.rowData) {

            let modalFields = { ...this.state.modalFields };
            modalFields.IsModalOpen = true;
            modalFields.HeaderContent = MessageConstants.DELETE_CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE;
            modalFields.ConfirmBtnText = MessageConstants.CONFIRM_BUTTON;
            modalFields.Size = "small";
            modalFields.data = event;
            this.setState({ modalFields: { ...modalFields } });

            
        }
    }
      handleUpdateAccess= (privileges)=>{
        let matrix = this.state.AccessMatrix;
        matrix.writelink = privileges.filter(x=>x.functionName ===UserprivilegeFunctionConstants.CASE_DATA
                                &&x.previlageName ===UserprivilegeFunctionConstants.WRITE).length===1;
        this.setState({ AccessMatrix: { ...matrix },isPrivilegesLoaded : true });
      }
    confirmationDialog = () => {
        return (
          <div>
            <React.Fragment>
              <STSLogModal
                modalProps={this.state.modalFields}
                closeModalClick={this.onCloseModalClick}
                submitModalClick={this.onSubmitModalClick}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          </div>
        );
      };
    
      onCloseModalClick = () => {
        let modalFields = { ...this.state.modalFields };
        modalFields.IsModalOpen = false;
        this.setState({ modalFields: { ...modalFields } });
      };
    
      onSubmitModalClick = event => {
        this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(true));
        SPLinksService.deleteSPLink(event.rowData.caseId, event.rowData.fileSq)
            .then((data) => {
                notify("Folder link deleted", MessageConstants.SUCCESS)
                this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(false));
                this.getAllFolderLinks();
            }, error => {
                notify("Error while deleting folder", MessageConstants.FAIL)
                this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(false));
            })
        this.onCloseModalClick();
        this.onResetClick();
      };

      onResetClick = () => {
        this.setState({linkURL:'',linkDesc:''});
      };
    getAllFolderLinks() {
        this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(true));
        if (this.state.folderLinks.length === 0) {
            this.setState({ folderLinks: [{}] })
        }
        SPLinksService.getSPLinks(this.props.caseId)
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    folderLinks: data.data
                })
                this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(false));
            }, error => {
                this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(false));
                notify("Error while getting folder links", MessageConstants.FAIL)
            })
    }

    getLinkGridLabels = () => {
        let labels = [{ header: 'Folder Description', field: 'linkDesc' },
        {
            header: 'Folder link', field: 'linkUrl',
            renderer: this.folderLinkTemplate
        }
        ];

        return labels;
    }

    folderLinkTemplate(data) {
        return (
            <a href={data.value} target="_blank">{data.value}</a>
            
        );
    }

    buildLinkGridLabels = () => {
        let gridLabels = this.getLinkGridLabels();
        let dataTableColumns = gridLabels.map((col, i) => {
            return (
                <DataTable.Column
                    key={col.field}
                    field={col.field}
                    header={col.header}
                // renderer={col.renderer}
                />
            )
        });

        return dataTableColumns;
    }

    saveFolderLink = () => {
        if (this.validateLinkForm()) {
            this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(true));
            let currentState = { ...this.state }
            SPLinksService.saveSPLink(this.props.caseId, currentState.linkURL, currentState.linkDesc)
                .then((data) => {
                    this.props.dispatch(LoaderAction.loaderStatus(false));
                    notify("Folder link saved", MessageConstants.SUCCESS);
                    this.getAllFolderLinks();
                    this.onResetClick();
                }, error => {
                    notify("Error while saving folder link", MessageConstants.FAIL)
                })
        }
    }
     
    validateLinkForm() {
        
        if (this.state.linkURL.length === 0) {
            notify("Sharepoint link is requried", MessageConstants.FAIL)
            return false;
        }

        if (this.state.linkDesc.length === 0) {
            notify("Link description is requried", MessageConstants.FAIL)
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    render() {
        var componentProps = {
            ...this.state,
            handleLinkInputChanges: this.handleLinkInputChanges,
            saveFolderLink: this.saveFolderLink,
            buildLinkGridLabels: this.buildLinkGridLabels,
            confirmationDialog: this.confirmationDialog,
            selectedData: this.selectedData,
            onDataTableCellClick: this.onDataTableCellClick
        }
        return (<CaseFileLinksView {
            ...componentProps
        }
        />)
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { AppReducer } = state;
    return {
      userSession: AppReducer.userSession
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CaseFileLinksComponent);
```

Component.jsx

```
export const CaseFileLinksView = props => {
    
    return (
        <div className="sts-create-proposal-wrapper">
            <div className="sts-create-proposal-form">
            {props.confirmationDialog()}
                <form className="proposal-create-form">
                    {props.AccessMatrix.writelink?(<div className="proposal-container">
                        <div className="form-input">
                            <Input
                                id={'ipLinkName'}
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Link"
                                icon="edit"
                                label="Sharepoint link"
                                value={props.linkURL || ''}
                                onChange={(event) => props.handleLinkInputChanges(event, "linkURL")}
                                indicator="required"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-input">
                            <Input
                                id={'ipLinkDesc'}
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Description"
                                icon="edit"
                                label="Link description"
                                name="linkDesc"
                                value={props.linkDesc || ''}
                                onChange={(event) => props.handleLinkInputChanges(event, "linkDesc")}
                                indicator="required"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-input">
                            <Button className = "save-button" type="primary" content="SAVE LINK" onClick={props.saveFolderLink} />
                        </div>
                    </div>): ("")}
                    <div className="proposal-container">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header title="Folder Links"></Card.Header>
                            <Card.Content>
                                <STSDataTable
                                    dataTableItems={props.folderLinks}
                                    onRowClick={props.selectedData}
                                    onCellClick={props.onDataTableCellClick}
                                    gridLabels={props.folderGridLabels}
                                    isNoDelete ={!props.AccessMatrix.writelink}
                                />

                            </Card.Content>
                        </Card>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Component.test.js

```
let wrapper;
let sampleUrlValue = "http://www.example.com"
const confirmationDialogue = () => { };
const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
const store = mockStore({
    AppReducer: {
        userSession: {
            isValid: true,
            userPrivileges: AccessMatrix.ReturnMockAccessMatrix()
        }
    }
});
let props = {};
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

beforeEach(() => {

    props = {
        isPrivilegesLoaded: false,
        AccessMatrix: {
            writelink: true,
        },
        confirmationDialog: confirmationDialogue
    }
    wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <CaseFileLinksComponent {...props} />
        </Provider>
    ).setProps(props);
})

describe("Case files link component", () => {
    it("Case files link component should load without crashing", () => {
        expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    })

    it("Component should have text box to enter URL", () => {
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        //expect(wrapper.find('Input#ipLinkName')).toHaveLength(1);
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `componentWillUpdate()` is deprecated since React v17, so either change it to `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()` or, better, transform it to `componentDidUpdate()`;
2. `componentWillUpdate()` is not called upon the initial rendering of the component.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, posting it here so that it helps someone. I removed the provider tag while mounting my component and it started working.

```
  wrapper = mount(
        <CaseFileLinksComponent store={store} />
    ).setProps(props);
```